# Universal Link How to forbid open all links except some?

Tags: ios, deep-linking, ios-universal-links, apple-app-site-association

apple-app-site-association:

```json
{
    "applinks": {
        "details": [
            {
                "appIDs": [
                    "XXXXXXXXXX.com.project",
                ],
                "components": [
                    "/*/news/*"
                ],
                "defaults": {
                    "caseSensitive": false 
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Associated Domains:

```
applinks:*.siteName.com
```

With this configuration it opens any link in app.

I **need** next links to open the app:

- https://test1.siteName.com/ru/news/101.html
- https://test2.siteName.com/en/news/101.html

And next to open site:

- https://test1.siteName.com
- https://test3.siteName.com

There are a lot of variations of subdomains (test1, test2, test3, test4...)

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that AASA file has a wrong format. While I investigate this functional, I've made a guide with useful information. https://github.com/NikKovIos/AASA-Universal-Links-Information/blob/main/README.md